# Where to verify if password needs a rehash in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, php-password-hash

I got the following code and nothing is getting inserted into my database and I can't figure out why.. is the `password_needs_rehash()` function at it's right spot?

I got a test where I echo out the new generated with a Javascript alert and it shows a new hash but the new hash is not getting inserted into the database. There must be a error in my logic but I can't find it.

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'mysqli.php';


$userID = strtolower($_POST['userID']);
$passwordFromForm = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;

//Select the password from the requested userID and put into variable
$sql = "SELECT password FROM userdata WHERE userID = '$userID'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$passwordFromDatabase = $row['password'];

$verified = password_verify($passwordFromForm, $passwordFromDatabase);

if($verified == 0){
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?triedLogin" />';

}else{

if(password_needs_rehash($passwordFromDatabase, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 14])){

    $passwordFromDatabase = password_hash($passwordFromDatabase, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 14]);

    echo "<script>alert('".$passwordFromDatabase."');</script>";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata ('password') VALUES ('$passwordFromDatabase')";

    //NOW LOGIN WITH NEW PASSWORD
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE userID = '$userID' AND password = '$passwordFromDatabase'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?triedLogin" />';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['userID'];
            unset($_SESSION['userID']);
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=app/index.php" />';
        }

}else{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE userID = '$userID' AND password = '$passwordFromDatabase'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=index.php?triedLogin" />';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['userID'];
        unset($_SESSION['userID']);
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=app/index.php" />';
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: This `INSERT INTO userdata ('password')` for one thing, is failing you, plus you never executed that query.

Comment: ...you are paying attention here, right? Probably not. Should I post an answer to get your attention instead?

Comment: *"is the rehash_password function at it's right spot?"* - Huh, what `rehash_password()` function?

Comment: but shouldn the insert request be executed when stated in a variable? I also saw that i had the sql twice now :O @Fred-ii-

Comment: *password_needs_rehash sorry, I'm tired haha

Comment: I take it your insert still doesn't work then. Ahmed's answer is really a glorified comment and not an answer/solution to this question, IMHO. We also don't know if your POST arrays contain values or not and what they are exactly.

Comment: the $_POST['userID'] & $_POST['password'] are the plain text coming from a form to login @Fred-ii-  I wrote this code now instead to somehow query the insert but nothing is getting inserted here either :( `$newEntry = "INSERT INTO 'userdata' ('password') VALUES ('$passwordFromDatabase')";
        $getgoing = mysqli_query($conn, $newEntry);`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: One more thing: Don't use the password from the database. If you've verified this is the correct password, use the password supplied by the user. You might have a hashed password with something like MD5 originally, so this is a better pattern to employ in a general sense.

Comment: thanks for the hint @tadman I'm not going to keep this structure, this is just in development and i will rewrite the whole mysql bit into pdo before any release ;)

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to take this opportunity to evaluate existing frameworks which implement this correctly and make full use of them. This stuff is very, very hard to get right.

Comment: I deleted my answer after all. I felt insulted seeing the other answer getting an upvote and not mine and didn't even cover a fraction of the problems with this question, what with the work I put into this. I knew I wouldn't see the end of this tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

- Make make sure your table field is large enough to hold that value because hash are very long, it will throw errors thus no INSERT.
- You should prepare your statements, I am surprised you don't do this yet you into password hashing.

Comment: Eh... you never run the `$sql` with the insert. You overwrite it with the `$sql` with the select right below it.

Comment: My password field is of the TEXT typ so it should fit the hashed string. I will prepare all the mysql inserts etc when the webapp is close to finished ;) I only follow others guides and the most available help is on the mysqli front, unfortunately. I will however rewrite everything later on before releasing ;) @Ahmed Daou

Comment: Thanks!!! I thought the first sql gets executed and then moves on to the next variable hehe @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: @Zoung Using `TEXT` for short strings is a complete waste. Use `VARCHAR(255)` for all generic strings, `TEXT` for anything that's >1KB, which a hashed password is obviously not.